# Pass variable to View Controller Embedded in Navigation Controller in Objective-C

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

I have embedded a destination viewcontroller in a navigation controller and am now unable to pass it a variable.

My code is:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//THis is the navigation controller 
    UIViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNav"];
//This is the view controller embedded in the nav
    IDNowVC* myVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
   myVC.sender = @1;//for contacts

   [self presentViewController:destVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After the launch of the VC, sender property is nil.  It is not getting the value @1.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have a comment that says:

> //This is the view controller embedded in the nav

However, the view controller below that comment is *not* the one embedded in your navigation controller. It's a completely new controller that is created at that line and disposed of at the end of the function.

You need something more like this:

```
UINavigationController *destVC = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNav"];
IDNowVC* myVC = destVC.childViewControllers[0];
myVC.sender = @1;
```

There might be some syntax issues with the above...

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  I guess you could also instantiate myVC from storyboard, then get the nav from myNav using [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myVC ];and launch myNav.  You just can't instantiate both from storyboard and expect them to be connected.

Comment: No. If you instantiate myVC from the storyboard, then it won't be connected to a UINavigationController.